# Java crawl web and store in cassandra

Tags: java, web-crawler

I have a java project for which I'd like to use a pre-built web crawler that gives me enough flexibility to be able to control which urls are crawled and then once the crawler has the output I want to control where to put it (cassandra with my own schema).

The big picture is I want to feed in a list of urls (Google and Bing searches) and then filter the urls that are returned. I want it to then crawl the filtered urls (I may possibly want to change the url query string, but that's not a hard requirement). I want to take the resulting html and parse it using Tika then pull the data out and store it.

I'm looking at Apache Droids, it's a good fit since it seems to do everything I've mentioned but there isn't any real documentation. I'd consider Nutch or Heritrix but the use cases seem to be more a full solution and after skimming I don't see anything that talks about how to do what want.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of thing? I mostly need some recommendations, but if you know of examples doing this sort of thing that'd be nice as well since I'm still pretty new to java.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say Droids is a well established framework yet. If you compare it to Nutch, which has a lot of history behind, I would expect it to be less stable and less documented. I have no experience with Droids, though.

As far as storing data in cassandra, I would recommend either https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax
or Hector 
https://github.com/hector-client/hector

I have used extensively Hector in the last year and have found it to be extremely simple and easy to use. It is faster to develop in Hector than its predecessors: pure Thrift/Pelops, but Hector is flexible enough to allow you to do the nitty gritty things which you expect from Thrift.

Recently I have also been eyeing astyanax as it is developed/supported by a larger team and tested on a larger scale, which is important for my current field of work. However, Hector is usually faster in implementing new features in new cassandra releases, so both libraries have their benefits.